# SQL Replace not inserting CHAR(13)

Tags: sql-server, replace, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

The intent of the below code is to replace a symbol with a Carriage Return for formatting purposes:

```
DECLARE @first VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @second VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;
DECLARE @total INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[RSummary]);

WHILE @cnt <= @total
BEGIN
    DECLARE @value VARCHAR(200) = (SELECT CID FROM [dbo].RSummary] WHERE ID = @cnt)
    SET @first = (SELECT Summary FROM [dbo].[RSummary] WHERE CID = @value)
    SET @second = REPLACE(@first,'|',CHAR(13))
    UPDATE [dbo].[RSummary] SET Summary = @second WHERE CID = @value
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END;
```

This works on my SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition on my dev box. When trying to run on the actual SQL instance (SQL Server 2017), with the exact same SQL Code, it replaces the symbol with a space character and not a carriage return; we have confirmed this in NotePad++. Also, the "results to text" option is not relevant but to assuage that concern it is checked to display CR/LF.

We have checked collation and table setup; it is all default values. Thoughts?

Comment: Why are you doing that in a cursor with multiple sub-selects? Why not use a single query? And if the purpose is for display, why not do the replace in code instead of T-SQL? Have you validated that its not a CR/CL in your application? Or only SSMS?

Comment: Your entire code can be replaced with `UPDATE [dbo].[RSummary] SET Summary = REPLACE(Summary,'|',CHAR(13));`

Comment: Seems unreproducible - you need to create a [mre] in [dbfiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: @DaleK We have tried a simple select statement: i.e. UPDATE [RSummary] SET Summary = REPLACE(Summary,'|',CHAR(13)); This did not work on the 2017 server box either. As for the second part, when trying to use INVOKE-SQLCMD or SQL Pramaters in PowerShell the Carraige Returns are stripped when inserted into the table.

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table? Do both the server and the column collations all match exactly?

Comment: The `update` will most certainly work... it seems likely the issue exists in how you are calling into SQL Server. You mention `INVOKE-SQLCMD` - you need to add how you are calling into SQL Server to your question. If you run those commands from SSMS they work.

Comment: BTW my point with the single line update was, not that it would solve the CR/LF issue, but that its the same functionality as your entire loop, but will perform a whole lot better.

Comment: @DaleK The UPDATE works but puts in a space instead of a Carriage Return. As for the INVOKE-SQLCMD it is not apart of the above problem. I only mentioned it because you asked why we are not trying a code solution.

Comment: I would say with high certainty that the update is not inserting a space... something else is affecting that. As I say, create a [mre] using dbfiddle.

Comment: @DaleK We understand the single line works, we tried that prior to the post.

Comment: @Charlieface No trigger and collations match.

Comment: What does `declare @Test nvarchar(max) = 'asdfasdfasdf|123451234521345'; select replace(@Test,'|',char(13));` return?

Comment: Or even better `declare @Test nvarchar(max) = '|'; select ascii(replace(@Test,'|',char(13)));`

Comment: @Charlieface returns 225

Comment: @DaleK That works, though it fails when we modify it to include the table.

Comment: So create us a dbfiddle using a temp table and some sample data. Although if you are getting 255 returned from Charlies test, something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: I still think it's a collation mismatch *somewhere*, Did you check server **and** database collation? What are the results of these `select ascii(char(13)), unicode(char(13)), unicode(nchar(13));  SELECT collation_name FROM sys.databases  WHERE name = 'whatever_mydatabase'`

Comment: @Charlieface All returned 13 and we did check the collation in both places.

Comment: @DaleK we tried a temp table prior as well, it works fine. The issue seems to be with the RSummary table or setup of the Server DB. Also on the point of the single line versus the loop, we understand the single line does the same thing as the loop. It is just leftover test code that will be cleaned up later. We are more concerned with why sql-server 2017 is not inserting the CHAR(13).

Comment: I think all that is left is for you to investigate the differences between your table and a temp table and your database settings. As we can see none of that we can't really help. Although you could script a create table and see if it shows anything.

Comment: So it's the collation of the column then `select name, collation_name from sys.columns where object_id =object_id('RSummary')` Either that or there is something going weird with the engine, are you on the latest Cumulative Update? Maybe try `dbcc checktable RSummary with no_infomsgs, all_errormsgs;`

Comment: How on earth is it returning 225? The pipe character is 124, the carriage return character is 13, neither one of those is 225.